# UnboundLocalError at /create_playlist/ local variable 'playlist' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, html, django, forms, exception

Here is my views.py :

```
def create_playlist(request):
    form = PlaylistForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        playlist = form.save(commit=False)
        playlist.name = request.name
        context={
            'playlist':playlist,
            'name':playlist_name,
        }

        return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', context)
    playlist.save()

    context = {
            "form": form,
        }
    return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', {'form': form,})
```

I have a model of `Playlist` and `forms.py` which contains all the fields of the Playlist model.I want users to be able to create their own playlist and for  that I made this but when I compile it, it gives my this error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /create_playlist/
local variable 'playlist' referenced before assignment
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/create_playlist/
Django Version: 1.9.6
Exception Type: UnboundLocalError
Exception Value:    
local variable 'playlist' referenced before assignment
```

EDIT:WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name'

Here is my models.py

```
class Playlist(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=False, blank=False,default='')
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Here is my forms.py :

```
class PlaylistForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Playlist
        fields = ['name', 'songs' ]
```

Comment: `playlist` defined inside `if` scope and you are using it outside too. In case `if` statement does not satisfies, this error may occur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the error because of following line. It is outside the `if form.is_valid():` block:

```
playlist.save()
```

I think you would like to have it inside the `if` block and before returning the response using `render`:

```
if form.is_valid():
    playlist = form.save(commit=False)
    playlist.name = request.name
    playlist.save()
    context={
        'playlist':playlist,
        'name':playlist_name,
    }

    return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', context)
```

Also, do note that `request.name` is not a known syntax.

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked.But when I click submit, it returns : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: How are you passing this `name` to the view?

Comment: What you added is the form and the model. It still doesn't tell us why would you use `request.name` when you are already using the form.

Comment: So how could I get the playlist name that the user just created?

Comment: You already must be getting in the form itself. It would be best if you go through the django documentation and practice the examples there. That would be a good learning exercise.

Comment: @blacklight: Any specific reasons why the accepted answer was changed?

Comment: I thought we could add more than one accepted answer. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

If form is not valid then `playlist` will not be defined.

Do this:

```
def create_playlist(request):
    form = PlaylistForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        playlist = form.save(commit=False)
        playlist.name = request.name
        playlist.save()
        context={
            'playlist':playlist,
            'name':playlist_name,
        }
        return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', context)
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, 'create_playlist.html', {'form': form,})
```

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked.But when I click submit, it returns : 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'name'